# need to extract multiple line text from big chunk of text in python language

Tags: python, regex

In python I have big text in multline.
I need to get the text between {{book  and }}
I tired using regular expression
problem is text inside is in mutiline string 
I tried `{{book (.+)` it gives me text only in first line
the I tried `{{book (.+) }}` this gives error

```
re.search("{{book .*?}", pagetext).group()
```

I have tried varied expression... problem is how do i go to next line in regular expression...

```
lot of other text {{book series |name = Twilight |image = [[File:The twilight saga hardback.jpg|260px|]] |language = English<!-- Do not link, per WP: OVERLINK --> |genre = [[Romance (novel)|Romance]], [[fantasy literature|fantasy]], [[young-adult fiction]] |publisher = [[Little, Brown and Company]] |pub_date = 2005â€“2008 |media_type = Print }} <lot of other text >
```

Comment: You will need to show the code you have tried, and an example of the text you are trying to extract.

Comment: re.search("{{book .*?}", pagetext).group()   .. I have tried varied expression...  problem is how do i go to next line in regular expression...     lot of other text
{{book series
|name          = Twilight
|image         = [[File:The twilight saga hardback.jpg|260px|]]
|language      = English<!-- Do not link, per WP: OVERLINK -->
|genre         = [[Romance (novel)|Romance]], [[fantasy literature|fantasy]], [[young-adult fiction]]
|publisher     = [[Little, Brown and Company]]
|pub_date      = 2005â€“2008
|media_type    = Print
}} <lot of other text >

Comment: user1036348: you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8111703/edit) to include the example (as @Michael did it for you).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.` to capture newline characters. Also, you should escape the braces because they are special characters in Python regex syntax.

```
re.search(r"\{\{book .*?\}\}", pagetext, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there could be nested `{{expr}}` then regular expressions are not enough e.g.:

```
pagetext = "start {{book with {{n{{e}}st{{e}}d t{{e}}xt}} t{{e}}xt}} {{e}}nd"
#XXX doesn't work: the text is truncated
print("Wrong:  %r" % re.search(r"\{\{book .*?\}\}", pagetext, re.DOTALL).group())
# -> Wrong:  '{{book with {{n{{e}}'
```

Adapting my answer from the
[get first paragraph from wikipedia article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7937855) question:

```
# extract everything from the first "{{book " to matching "}}"
prefix, sep, rest = pagetext.partition("{{book ")
if sep: # found the first "{{"
    depth = 1
    prevc = None
    for i, c in enumerate(rest):
        if c == "{" and  prevc == c:  # found "{{"
            depth += 1
            prevc = None # match "{{{ " only once
        elif c == "}" and prevc == c: # found "}}"
            depth -= 1
            if depth == 0: # found matching "}}"
                pagetext = sep + rest[:i+1] # include "}}"
                break
            prevc = None # match "}}} " only once
        else:
            prevc = c
print(pagetext)
```

#### Output

```
{{book with {{n{{e}}st{{e}}d t{{e}}xt}} t{{e}}xt}}
```